# Arduino is making an automatic feeder, but nothing is done

Tags: esp32

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <WiFiEsp.h>

#include <WiFiEspClient.h>

#include <WiFiEspServer.h>

#include <WiFiEspUdp.h>

#include <TimeLib.h>

#include <TimeAlarms.h>

#include <Servo.h>

#define GPIO2 0

Servo servo;

int GP0val = 0;

int value1 = 0;

const char* ssid = "??";

const char* password = "??";

WiFiEspServer server(80);

Servo myservo;

void setup()

{
myservo.attach(9);

```
Serial.begin(9600);

setTime(14,12,0,7,9,23); 

Alarm.alarmRepeat(14,13,30,MoringAlarm);

Alarm.alarmRepeat(14,14,00,EveningAlarm);

pinMode(7,INPUT_PULLUP);

Serial.print("Connecting to ");

Serial.println(ssid);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)     {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
```

}

```
Serial.println("");

Serial.println("WiFi connected.");

Serial.print("IP address : http://");

Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

server.begin();
```

}

void loop() {

```
 Alarm.delay(1000);

 digitalCloockDisplay();

 WiFiEspClient client=server.available();

 String req = client.readStringUntil('\\r');

 if(digitalRead(9)==LOW){

 myservo.write(170);

 delay(300);
```

}

else

{

```
myservo.write(0);

delay(300);
```

}

if (req.indexOf("/gpio2/1") != -1) {

```
GP0val = 1;


if (GP0val == 1) {  

  value1 += 90;

  delay(1000);

  myservo.write(value1);

  if (value1 == 90) {  

    delay(2000);

    value1 = 0;

    myservo.write(value1);

    GP0val = 0;

  }
```

}

}

}

void MoringAlarm() {

```
Serial.println("OPEN");

myservo.write(90);

delay(1000);
```

}

void EveningAlarm() {

```
Serial.println("CLOSE ");

myservo.write(-90);

delay(1000);
```

}

void digitalCloockDisplay() {

```
Serial.print(hour());

printDigits(minute());

printDigits(second());

Serial.println();
```

}

void printDigits(int digits) {

```
Serial.print(":");

if (digits \< 10) {

    Serial.print('0');

    Serial.print(digits);
```

}

}

Set the current wifi, button and time
I'm making a servo motor to feed him
Currently, the code below doesn't show errors, but it doesn't make any errors. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).